# How do i add music from a NAS to an iPhone?

Tags: iphone, itunes, data-synchronization, music, nas

I have a Nas system setup, i can play music through itunes with it but i can not add songs off my nas to a playlist in itunes or copy songs over to my iPhone. am i missing something here or does apple not allow that?

Comment: Which NAS? Is it running an iTunes Server you access via iTunes?

Comment: Your answer will vary by model. Is it a WD, QNAP, Synology, or. . .?

Answer (score 1):

Try the menu and select Advanced , create aac version. Then try to add it to your device. hope it helps. or import the songs to your library. good luck. I hope it works for you.